# my inapp browser path is not closing when i click on Close button on app given location.href = 'mobile/close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap-plugins

here is my client side code iam opening browser .

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(path, '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=yes,closebuttoncaption=Close');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
    if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
        ref.close();
    }
});
```

in server by clicking close button iam writting to close inappbrowser is 
 location.href = 'mobile/close';

Answer (score 0):

In  Config file iam using plugin with giving version means it takes latest plugin . in latest version if inappp browser is not working ,so i have seen which date i have added plugin in project so that date what ever version is there that version is given in config file so it worked .

these is my starting plugin in config file 
 now changed to 
  
for white list plugin i have given version
       
and removed some unused plugins in config file 
  version is gap:plugin name = "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.6.1"

Answer (score 0):

and also removed  plugin in config fileThen it is worked but while uploading apk to appstore it is getting error ,so i have  putplugin changed to iframe. open in new div.

Answer (score 0):

in config file i have added 
      
so the inappbrowser is not closing . 
 i have removed this configuration file
 
i have solved issue .